# varibles declared outside __init__ Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, variables, init

Why variables declared outside **init** method do not posses additivity property?
For example i have the following class:

```
class Trade:
    allTrades = []
    netPosition = 0

    def __init__(self, qty):
        self.quantity = qty

        self.allTrades.append(self.quantity)
        self.netPosition += self.quantity
```

`allTrades` (empty list) and `netPosition` variables are defined outside the **init** method while quantity variable defined inside.

Next I create 2 objects of my class and print AllTrades and netPosition for either of them:

```
deal1=Trade('long', 50, 31)
deal2=Trade('long', 16, 39)

print(deal2.allTrades)
print(deal2.netPosition)
```

And as far as I see `allTrades` (list) variable is additive while `netPosition` is not:
`print(deal2.allTrades)` returns [50, 16].
And `print(deal2.netPosition)` returns 16 however I assume that it should return 66

How can I make `print(deal2.netPosition)` return 66 instead of 16?

Comment: lists are mutable, ints are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `__init__` function creates two object variables which are references to the class variables of the same name.  So far so good.

When you call `self.allTrades.append` you are modifying (or *mutating*) your `allTrades` object, which is shared between all the objects of your class.

When you do `self.netPosition +=` you are *not* modifying `netPosition` because numbers are immutable.  Instead you're replacing your reference with another one to a *different* number object.  That means you've broken the connection between your object variable and your class variable.  No other objects will see those changes.

To get what you expect, you need to put your number inside another mutable object.

```
netPosition = [0]

self.netPosition = netPosition

self.netPosition[0] += self.quantity
```

Comment: It's more than just the immutability of integers. No instance attribute named `allTrades` is ever created. Rather, `self.allTrades` *resolves* to `Trade.allTrades` in the absence of an instance attribute by that name.  For `self.netPosition`, the situation is a little tricker, but I think the result is `self.netPosition = Trade.netPosition.__iadd__(self.quantity)`, where the class attribute is used to produce a value to assign to a new instance attribute that will shadow the class attribute.

Comment: @chepner you're right, I was imagining an assignment there that didn't actually exist.  My bad.